# Real input to FFTW

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

When I use FFTW, specifically the plan creation function `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d()`, for purely real input, the only "planner flag" (FFTW's terminology) which works is `FFTW_ESTIMATE`.  Any of the others which I try, viz., `FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE`, `FFTW_MEASURE`, and `FFTW_PATIENT`, all generate an output file with all zeros.

I have tried changing the number of input data items from powers of 2 to otherwise.  That makes no difference.

Scilab uses FFTW for its `fft()` and thus I am able to compare the output from my C++ program with the output from Scilab for the same input data file.  When I use `FFTW_ESTIMATE` the two outputs match.

I have read the FFTW documentation.  I cannot determine why the other planner flags do not work.

I am interested in using the `FFTW_MEASURE` planner flag since once the plan is formulated, I will want to use it repeatedly.

Below is my code.  I have **not** included the fftw3.h file as I have not made any changes to it.

```
#pragma once

// FFT_05.h
//#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "fftw3.h"

#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
```

```
// FFT_05_c.cpp

#include "FFT_05.h"

//*****************************************************************************
int32_t main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::fstream data_File;
    std::string directory = "C:/Documents/Visual Studio 2022/Projects/";
    directory += "FFT_05/Scilab programs/02/";
    std::string file_Name = "Time_domain_input.txt";
    data_File.open(directory + file_Name, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

    double input_Value = 0.0;
    int data_Count = 0;

    if (data_File.is_open()) {

        while (!data_File.eof()) {
            data_File >> input_Value;
            data_Count++;
        }

    }

    std::cout << data_Count << std::endl;

    data_File.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    double* in;
    fftw_complex* out;
    fftw_plan p;

    in = (double*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * data_Count);

    int data_Count_Out = (data_Count / 2) + 1;
    out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * data_Count_Out);

    int i = 0;

    while (!data_File.eof()) {

        data_File >> input_Value;
        
        in[i++] = input_Value;
    }

    data_File.close();

    //for (int i = 0; i < data_Count; i++) {

    //  //std::cout << in[i][0] << ", " << in[i][1] << std::endl;
    //  std::cout << (i + 1) << ". " << in[i] << std::endl;
    //}

    //std::cout << "\n\n";

    // FFTW procedure
    p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(data_Count, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    if (!p) {

        std::cout << "FFTW plan is NULL\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    fftw_execute(p);

    fftw_destroy_plan(p);

    std::fstream FFT_Data_File;
    FFT_Data_File.open(directory + "frequency_Domain_File_Name_c.txt", 
        std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::trunc);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < (data_Count_Out - 1); i++) {
        FFT_Data_File << out[i][0] << " " << out[i][1] << std::endl;
    }

    FFT_Data_File << out[(data_Count_Out - 1)][0] << " " << out[(data_Count_Out - 1)][1];

    FFT_Data_File.close();

    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html): `"Important: the planner overwrites the input array during planning unless a saved plan (see Wisdom) is available for that problem, so you should initialize your input data after creating the plan. The only exceptions to this are the FFTW_ESTIMATE and FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY flags, "`.  So you need to initialize your input data `in` *after* the call to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d` if you want to use `FFTW_MEASURE` (although you might be able to use `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT`).

Comment: Also note that `MEASURE` is only useful if you are going to reuse the plan many times. Because it actually does the FFT computation multiple times to see which one is fastest. If you just want to compute a single FFT, use `ESTIMATE`.

Comment: Since the plan requires the input data, I made a copy of the input data and then restored the input data from the copy before executing the plan.  I also followed FFTW's direction on how to save the wisdom after the plan is formulated with `FFTW_MEASURE` and then recall the wisdom before plan execution.  The code now produces a non-zero output file.

Comment: My desire is to use FFTW with audio input data wherein I take the fft of a portion of the audio data repeatedly and multiply it by a DSP filter transfer function in the frequency domain.  From what I understand, using `FFTW_MEASURE` in formulating the plan will be useful for that effort since the resulting, efficient plan will be appropriate to all the slices of the audio data as long as that audio data, which will be voice or music, does not vary "too much".  Does that make sense?

Comment: I do not think the chosen plan is related to the data itself, but on the sizes and hardware properties.

Comment: Thanks all.  I have been able to write working code which will suit my purposes.  Sebastian, you are correct in that the plan will be generated even with no data for the input.  The input vector only needs to be declared and sized.